# google Measurement Protocol giving weird response

Tags: curl, google-analytics, php-7, guzzle, measurement-protocol

I am trying to set this up using php7 and guzzle for my rest API. when i send the request in curl using cli to the debug url i get a nice json response

```
{
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1\u0026t=pageview\u0026tid=UA-1234567-1\u0026uid=UA-1234567-1\u0026dh=test.domain.com\u0026dp=/api/user/verify/flow"
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

but if i send it to prod url i get weird response everytime

```
GIF89a▒▒▒▒▒,D;
```

does anyone know how to solve this?

this is what i run on cli

```
curl -X POST -d 'v=1&t=pageview&tid=UA-xxxxxxxxx-1&uid=UA-xxxxxxxxx-1&dh=test.domain.com&dp=%2Fiwsapi%2Fuser%2Fverify%2Fflow' https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect
```

for non debug mode i just remove the the debug

```
curl -X POST -d 'v=1&t=pageview&tid=UA-xxxxxxxxx-1&uid=UA-xxxxxxxxx-1&dh=test.domain.com&dp=%2Fiwsapi%2Fuser%2Fverify%2Fflow' https://www.google-analytics.com/collect
```

In guzzle i am building it like so

```
$promise = $guzzle->post("/debug/collect", [
                                'proxy' => [
                                    'http'  => 'http://proxy:8080',
                                    'https'  => 'http://proxy:8080', 
                                ],
                                'form_params'=>[
                                    'v'=>1,
                                    't'=>'pageview',
                                    'tid'=>GOOGLE_ID,
                                    'uid'=>$_SERVER['HTTP_CTVFNTUSERNAME'],
                                    'dh'=>WWWHOST,
                                    'dp'=>$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
                                    //'dt'=>'homepage'
                                ]
                            ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Response Codes](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference#response-codes)
>
> The Measurement Protocol will return a 2xx status code if the HTTP request was received. The Measurement Protocol does not return an error code if the payload data was malformed, or if the data in the payload was incorrect or was not processed by Google Analytics.
>
> If you do not get a 2xx status code, you should NOT retry the request. Instead, you should stop and correct any errors in your HTTP request.

The measurement protocol doesn't actually validate your hits in anyway the only response you will ever get is an 1x1 pixel image that being `GIF89a▒▒▒▒▒,D`;

So there is really nothing to solve its working as it should.   The only one that will send you a proper response is the debug endpoint which you appear to be using

Comment: they should mention that in their docs!!!. thanks for the response, it had me puzzled. do you think i should call the debug 1st and then send it off if successful?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference#response-codes  <--- they do the code i quotes is copied form the docs :)    I normally call debug when i am in development once my code works and i push it to production i dont bother calling debug anymore

Comment: is there anyway to validate the image

Comment: No the image is always the same like I said that measurement api is fire and forget there is no validation on the response

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the User-Agent header to the request.
Further explanation is here:
https://groups.google.com/g/google-analytics-measurement-protocol/c/VVaoSU-2FB4?pli=1